# Getting Controller Instance From TokenValidatedContext (Net Core, JwtBearerMiddleware)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

Hello fellow programmers, I am creating an API with authentication. On the `OnTokenValidated` function I want to get my controller instance to save the claims in an **API Base Controller**.
The context variable is a `TokenValidatedContext`and has a `HttpContext` property but this HttpContext doesn't have the usual methods (I would just get the RouteData with it's usual methods).
I know there's many ways to access easily the claims from any controller, but I need it in the ApiBaseController because reasons. My code looks like this in the startup:

```
 options.JwtBearerEvents = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        return jwtMiddleware.AuthenticationFailed(context); 
                    }
                    ,OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        return jwtMiddleware.MessageReceived(context);
                    },
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        //var claims = context.Principal.Claims.ToList();
                        return jwtMiddleware.TokenValidated(context);
                    },
                    OnChallenge = context =>
                    {
                        return jwtMiddleware.Challenge(context);
                    }
                };
```

Maybe I can save the claims in another callback function? I searched everywhere for a similar situation but I haven't found anything yet.
Do you have any suggestions for this? Help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to save `claims` inside Controller? They are normally saved inside `Principal` object.

Comment: @Win The claims are in the Principal indeed. I told that to my leader. I guess I'll prolongate the task until my leader change his mind. I thought I just might give it a shot asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @win said in his comment, the claims are accesible in the `Principal`. So you should use it as a normal person would do.

**I**, on the other hand, **had to** save the same claims on a base controller. So I did the following:

- Added a singleton instance of the `IHttpContextAccessor`.
- Created a model which contains the information of the claims I'll save.
- I created a method which invokes the singleton context and its claims and returns the model with the information.
- In the base controller, if the instance of the model is null I assign it with the method mentioned before.

I don't recommend this last procedure, just go with the `Princpal` but could help someone else with a similar objective.